# Postgresql, days from date interval

Tags: postgresql

I need to find all rows from database table, for which the difference between columns `date_start` and `date_end` is exactly 3 days. I looked through postgresql documentation like http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html, and have already created several queries, for example:

```
"SELECT e FROM Events e WHERE date_part('day',(e.date_end - e.date_start)) = 3"
```

but unfortunately my editor give an error `"The query contains a malformed ending"` and `"The identification variable 'date_part' is not defined in the FROM clause"` (Eclipse). Could anyone explain me, where is my mistake?

**EDIT1:**

Maybe eclipse does not know all postgresql functions and I have to import some library or add something into query to make date_part function visible for the environment?

Comment: In your query after the Events you are mentioning e what is that ?

Comment: I guess, it is synonym for the table name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I did not find solution using postgresql queries, just cause my eclipse editor always give me an errors referenced to the postgresql functions (do not know some of them).
But I found some around way. Just selected general information from the table, and all required checkes I have done in java classes.